# Model not changing in angular when using inside document.addEventListener() property

Tags: javascript, angular, document

I'm trying to update my model name `this.name` on click that is inside `document.getElementById('source-selection').addEventListener`.Not sure why its not changing while a simple alert inside that function triggers.
I've also tried the same with `ngOnChanges` as well.

```
ngOnInit() {
      document.getElementById('source-selection').addEventListener('click', function (evt: any) {
       alert('test');
       this.name = `My Angular Test On Click`;
    });
   }
    ngOnChanges() {
      document.getElementById('source-selection').addEventListener('click', function (evt: any) {
       alert('test');
       this.name = `My Angular Test On Click`;
    });
   }
```

Please find the plunker link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/pBLk409W9cKVkvCpIvjX?p=preview) to experiment

Comment: `this` inside event callback is not what you think

Comment: So `this` will not work?Any other solution?

Comment: bind `this` to callback function like `function () {}.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the 'this' inside the callback function is not the instance of the component. It has been changed because every new function defined its own 'this' value.

A solution is to use arrow function that binds automatically the 'this' to the function:

```
document.getElementById('source-selection').addEventListener('click',  (evt: any) => {
   this.name = `My Angular Test On Click`;
});
```

In an arrow function, the this value of the enclosing execution context is used. More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1):

First, you used `this` in a non fat-arrow function. This means `this` doesn't refer to your component, but to the function.

Second, Angular offers a wide range of event listeners, why would you use the vanillaJS one ? this is counter productive !

replace your html with this

```
<div id="source-selection" (click)="changeName()">...</div>
```

And in your TS add this

```
changeName() { this.name = 'My Angular Test On Click'; }
```

Comment: Thanks but  I don't want to use (click)

Comment: May I know why ? Because if you don't use the framework you use, there's no point of using the framework at all !

Comment: If you don't want to use the (click) in the markup, you can use Angular's host listeners and bindings. This is another "angular way" of doing this, instead of using vanilla javascript.

Comment: This implementation I wanted to use https://www.predix-ui.com/#/elements/px-dropdown that dosen't support (click) directly.But exposes many events that can be listened using `document.addEventListener` property

Comment: Given that it's written `Framework-agnostic Code` in big letters, I highly doubt you can't use (click) ... But whatever floats your boat, in this case, see @ChristianBenseler's answer, he gives you the solution to make it work !

Comment: I will just add one last thing, `ngOnChanges` is used for Input/Output changes, not current model changes, so if it doesn't work, now you know hwy :)

Comment: Thanks @trichetriche for clarification